# Restore from Production to Development

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-online, central-administration, backup

I have two different servers with Sharepoint 2010 standard edition setup. I have two different SQL database servers(DEV_Content and PROD_Content) for these two environments. I would like to create webapplication backup from production and restore it in development server. So that two server looks similar with same site collections and content database as in Prod Server. I copied webapplication backup from Prod. Server without any problem. But when I try to restore webapplication to development, instead of Development SQL server, it shows Production server. Does this mean , if I restore my backup files. it will overwrite to Prod server (which I dont want)?
Here is the image:[image]

Here in this image, all the default setup are the setups from my Prodcution server.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you out...
I perform all of my backups and restores using Powershell.

Example:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://your.DevServer.com -Path C:\Backups\your-backup-name.bak -Force
```

Perform this script on the Dev server and you will always know that you are restoring the data to the correct server.